# Remove top row from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I have  a dataframe that looks like this:

```
         level_0              level_1 Repo Averages for 27 Jul 2018
0  Business Date           Instrument                           Ccy
1     27/07/2018  GC_AUSTRIA_SUB_10YR                           EUR
2     27/07/2018    R_RAGB_1.15_10/18                           EUR
3     27/07/2018    R_RAGB_4.35_03/19                           EUR
4     27/07/2018    R_RAGB_1.95_06/19                           EUR
```

I am trying to get rid of the top row and only keep

```
   Business Date           Instrument         Ccy
0     27/07/2018  GC_AUSTRIA_SUB_10YR         EUR
1     27/07/2018    R_RAGB_1.15_10/18         EUR
2     27/07/2018    R_RAGB_4.35_03/19         EUR
3     27/07/2018    R_RAGB_1.95_06/19         EUR
```

I tried `df.columns.droplevel(0)`  but not successful  any help is more than welcome

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? It looks like an issue in reading the data.

Comment: You are likely to get answers quicker if you have runnable code in your question.

Comment: It is an automated file that  has a weird structure. the top row it is like a title. So I have to read in everything and then delete undesirable rows

Comment: `pd.read_csv('myfile', skiprows = 1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using slicing.

`df = df[1:]`

This will remove the first row of your dataframe.

Comment: even if the answer is accepted, have you tested it on the given example?

Comment: agree with @Joe , this example is not working.

Answer (score 7):

You can try so:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.reindex(df.index.drop(0)).reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns.name = None
```

Output:

```
  Business Date           Instrument  Ccy
0    27/07/2018  GC_AUSTRIA_SUB_10YR  EUR
1    27/07/2018    R_RAGB_1.15_10/18  EUR
2    27/07/2018    R_RAGB_4.35_03/19  EUR
3    27/07/2018    R_RAGB_1.95_06/19  EUR
```

Answer (score 6):

You can take advantage of the parameter `header` ([Read here more about the header parameter in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)).

Let's say that you have the following dataset

```
df = pd.read_csv("Prices.csv")
print(df)
```

That outputs

```
              0       1     2         3         4
0      DATA      SESSAO  HORA  PRECO_PT  PRECO_ES
1      1/1/2020  0       1     41,88     41,88   
2      1/1/2020  0       2     38,60     38,60   
3      1/1/2020  0       3     36,55     36,55
```

By simply passing the `header = 0` like this

```
df = pd.read_csv("Prices.csv", header=0)
print(df)
```

You will get what you want

```
           DATA  SESSAO  HORA PRECO_PT PRECO_ES
0      1/1/2009  0       1     55,01    55,01  
1      1/1/2009  0       2     56,13    56,13  
2      1/1/2009  0       3     50,59    50,59  
3      1/1/2009  0       4     45,83    45,83  
4      1/1/2009  0       5     42,07    41,90
```

Comment: This gives a working solution with a clear explanation AND links to relevant documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
df.drop(row_start, row_end)
```

This will help

Comment: don't use code snippets if the code is not executable, use code formatting instead.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the comment by jeremycg. It works very well and is succinct. Just want more people to see, here it is again -

```
my_df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\path\to\my\file.csv", skiprows = 1)
```